# How to delete datarow cells from certain index?

Tags: c#

I need to empty datarow from certain cell index, where previous condition has been met.

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dtSecondTab.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         if (dtSecondTab.Rows[i]["Month"].ToString() != "" && dtSecondTab.Rows[i]["Month"].ToString() != Convert.ToInt32(cbMonth.Text).ToString())
         {
             //here I need to clear datarow from cell index 6 to the end of the row                      
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What means "clear" exactly?

Comment: It means I need to convert any value from those cells to DBNull.Value. I have about 150 columns in that table, and I need to leave only first 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int cellIndex = 6; cellIndex < dtSecondTab.Columns.Count; cellIndex++)
{
    dtSecondTab.Rows[i][cellIndex] =  DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: cellIndex < dtSecondTab.Columns.Count - 1 -  should it be? I don't know I was just thinking because of the index thing.

Comment: @FarhanAnam: no, i'm using `<` not `<=`

Comment: Yes, that's the loop I was looking from. Thank you very much Tim ;)